# OData binding parent's entity property in XML view

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I have encountered a problem while binding my OData service to a ListItem in SAPUI5. To demonstrate my problem, let's consider this simple OData service:

```
Task: {
  ID: '100',
  Name: 'TaskName'
  Parent: {
    ID: '10',
    Name :'ParentName'
  }
}
```

I tried binding my controller to the service, but i can only retrieve the "ID" value of the text parameter, if i try to do a relative binding (in this case : to retrieve the Parent's ID), it doesn't seem to work..

```xml
<List items="{/Task}">
  <CustomListItem>
    <Button text="ID" tooltip="{Parent/ID}"/>
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make use of navigation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483541/how-to-make-use-of-navigation-property)

Comment: As suggested in the above linked answer, what you need is a navigation property with which you can do `tooltip="{ToParent/ID}"` whereas `"ToParent"` is the name of the navigation property to a single entity (not a collection).

Answer (score 1):

```
Task: [{
      ID : '100',
      Name :'TaskName'
      Parent :{
               ID :'10'
               Name :'ParentName'
              }
     }]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with `<Button text="ID" tooltip="/Parent/ID"/>`. Observe "/" before Parent node.